# Excel change by target VBA isn't being triggered when values are pasted into range

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code that that activates as a `worksheet_change` event. Everything works great with manually inputted data however the change event doesn't work when values are pasted into the various ranges. Any thoughts why that's happening and better yet a solution?
Thank you

```vb
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RNG1 As Range
    Dim RNG2 As Range
    Dim RNG3 As Range
    Dim RNG4 As Range
    Dim RNG5 As Range
    Dim RNG6 As Range
    Dim RNG7 As Range
    Dim RNG8 As Range
    Dim RNG9 As Range
    Dim RNG10 As Range

    Dim r As Range
    Dim S As Range
    
    Set RNG1 = Sheet8.Range("$AP$46:$AP$145")
    Set RNG2 = Sheet8.Range("$BA$46:$BA$145")
    Set RNG3 = Sheet8.Range("$BL$46:$BL$145")
    Set RNG4 = Sheet8.Range("$BW$46:$BW$145")
    Set RNG5 = Sheet8.Range("$CH$46:$CH$145")
    Set RNG6 = Sheet8.Range("$CS$46:$CS$145")
    Set RNG7 = Sheet8.Range("$DD$46:$DD$145")
    Set RNG8 = Sheet8.Range("$DO$46:$DO$145")
    Set RNG9 = Sheet8.Range("$DZ$46:$DZ$145")
    Set RNG10 = Sheet8.Range("$EK$46:$EK$145")
   
    
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Union(RNG1, RNG2, RNG3, RNG4, RNG5, RNG6, RNG7, RNG8, RNG9, RNG10)) Is Nothing Then
        Set MyRange = Sheet3.Range("A2:C1000")
        Set r = Sheet3.Range("A2:C1000").Find(What:=Target.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not r Is Nothing Then   'name is found
            Target.Offset(0, 2) = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(Target.Value, MyRange, 3, False), "")
            Target.Offset(0, 1) = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(Target.Value, MyRange, 2, False), "")
        End If
    End If
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Union(RNG1, RNG2, RNG3, RNG4, RNG5, RNG6, RNG7, RNG8, RNG9, RNG10)) Is Nothing Then
        Set myrange2 = Sheet1.Range("B2:B25")
        Set S = Sheet1.Range("B2:B25").Find(What:=Target.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If S Is Nothing Then 'name is not found
            Target.Interior.Color = RGB(208, 208, 80)
        End If
    End If

    If Target.Value = "" Then
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If
        
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` will cause the sub to exit if your pasting affects more than a single cell.

Comment: Hi Leosch. Removing that line of the code allows for the change event to be triggered when pasting but it causes a type mismatch error with the last IF statement. I included this statement to remove the formatting that had been applied to the cell if its contents needs to be deleted. Can you suggest a work around or alternative?

Comment: If `target` contains more than one cell, `Target.Value` is invalid (it's an 2-dimensional array in that case). You will need to loop over all cells (eg `For Each cell in target`).

Comment: Thanks FunThomas. adding that loop solved the issue